# How to read text from a text field and input it into a database table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I have linked up a database to my Java application using the JDBC in Netbeans.
On my database I have a table with 3 fields :

- ID
- FirstName
- Surname

I am looking to type a number into the id text field in the application, click save and allow the id inputted by the user from the text field save in the ID section in the database table.

I am a student new to all of this so please forgive me if I am asking the right way or in the wrong section, I have already searched thoroughly for a working example, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: please share some code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code to share? What kind of application do you want to build (desktop, web)? What technology do you use to make the UI (Swing, JSP, JavaFX)? As is this question is too broad to provide you an answer.

Comment: i think you should google-up this one !

Comment: hey you want the code for java or (jsp, jsp-servlet)...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
Statement stmt = null;
String query = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ("+ID.getText+","+FirstName.getText+","+SurName.getText+")";
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
}catch (SQLException e ) {
    //print exception
}
```